# Detecting simulated keyboard/mouse input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, simulation

Is there a way to detect simulated keyboard/mouse input on Windows. For example, a user types something on his keyboard vs sendKeys/PostMessage/On-screen keyboard. Is there a way that I can distinguish between the two?

EDIT: Perhaps an example would help. I am making a game and want to distinguish between real input vs WinAPI synthesizing keyboard/mouse messages.

Comment: It's a rather funny question, because if the answer were yes, I can almost see someone else asking: How do you prevent applications from detecting synthesized input?

Comment: @Lambert: That's an easy one, I've got five answers so far.  (A) virtual keyboard device driver (B) virtual machine (C) PS/2 keystroke generator (D) robotic arm depressing keys on a "real" keyboard (E) [pitching machine](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-5503582578132361295)

Comment: @Lambert: I was really just looking for an excuse to post a link to animusic :)

Comment: @Ben: Yeah I really enjoy those, I've seen them on TV on KQED. The person who made them must have been very talented. :)

Comment: @Lambert: [Video for the robotic arm](http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2010-04/video-worlds-fastest-pick-and-place-robot-takes-wiimote-challenge) too.  Even waving the keyboard around can't defeat it.

Comment: All I can say is wow... O____O

Comment: ha ha, add more memory and you got yourself a Turing machine!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid chat speak, but... lol.

Comment: you could do this the rootkit way, hook the system's SendInput, and make sure it never touches your application. you could even use a userland rootkit for this, hooking every other userland process' SendInput..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but the on-screen keyboard (and other applications that simulate user input) most probably uses the SendInput API:

> SendInput operates at the bottom level of the input stack. It is just a backdoor into the same input mechanism that the keyboard and mouse drivers use to tell the window manager that the user has generated input.
>   Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/21/10107494.aspx

So there is probably no way to tell whether the input is coming from a "real" keyboard or not.

Comment: "coming from a real keyboard" isn't even sufficient.  Dave wanted to know if it's a user typing on his keyboard (and not, I suppose, a robotic manipulator arm depressing keys on that same keyboard).

Comment: also ofc, you could do this the rootkit way, hook the system's SendInput API, and make sure it never touches your application. you could even use a userland rootkit for this, hooking every other userland process' SendInput.

Comment: "*So there is probably no way to tell whether the input is coming from a "real" keyboard or not*" - actually, there is.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to distinguish between "real" input and "simulated" input (assuming it is being generated with `keybd_event()`/`mouse_event()` or `SendInput()`) is to use a low-level keyboard/mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`. The `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook callbacks provide `INJECTED` flags for simulated input.

Answer (score 7):

Starting form Windows 8 there's the [`GetCurrentInputMessageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcurrentinputmessagesource) function. You can use it, and check the `originId` enum for the following value:

> `IMO_INJECTED` - The input message has been injected (through the `SendInput` function) by an application that doesn't have the **UIAccess** attribute set to `TRUE` in its manifest file.

Comment: MSDN says the injected flag is not set for UIAccess=true manifested apps