# How to detect if mouse click is legit or automated?

Tags: c++, vb.net

How to know if a mouse click is simulated or not? When mouse click send by a program or real mouse device

... I'm programming a system detection for a game to avoid bots, autoclicks,etc that only accept legit mouse clicks

Comment: Ignore the click. If there is another click then it is likely to be a real mouse. Ignore that one and if you get many clicks you can be sure there is an irate user trying to click....

Comment: Not possible. The computer interprets them the same way, that's kind of the point. Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible for a simulated mouse event to have the same functionality as a real mouse click. There's undoubtedly a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @T33C If this (thin on details) requirement requires the detection for some useful purpose, to alter program behavior or coerce the user then it must block the use of scripting altogether. Otherwise its a pointless exercise.

Comment: Your making AI painful, by not allowing two games to play against each other.  Neural networks may take a lot of *clicks* to train.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553777/detecting-simulated-keyboard-mouse-input

Answer (score 11):

This depends a bit on the kind of application you are writing, but if you can, I would watch the cursor movement, not the clicks.
Human mouse movement has non-uniform speeds, reaction times, imprecisions (clicks on different coordinates of your buttons, etc...).

Also, you can defend a gui against bots by randomly requiring an interaction that is hard to script. For example: If scripts depend upon buttons being always in the same position, I would make sure that, while trying to remain intuitive, the dialog should pop up in slightly different positions every time.

Otherwise: There is no way to detect if the mouse is a real one or a really well simulated one. The Windows HID/MacOS/Linux driver layer abstracts away the distinction between  Mice, TrackPens, TrackBalls, draw-pads, touch screens... and of course script-mice...

Answer (score 7):

Although the blog post itself is about a different issue, I refer you to Raymond Chen's excellent [Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/15/10129271.aspx). In this specific blog post he talks about the validity of message parameters going into an application, but also makes the point that:

> There's no point discussing the possibility that the sender of the message is playing tricks and lying to you because (1) your program should just go along with the ruse and respond to fake menu messages as if they were real menu messages, because (2) there's no way to tell that you're being lied to anyway. To detect lying, you'd have to be able to read into the mindset of the programmer who sent you the message.

Essentially the argument is that you should respond to mouse clicks as mouse clicks, regardless of how those clicks were generated.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the mouse event flags LLMHF_INJECTED and LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED or utilize input hooks to monitor mouse input data, where malformed data may indicated that input was injected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

Answer (score 2):

Is [mouse keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys) simulated mouse input or legit? The point of simulating mouse input is to make them look exactly like real mouse input. **If the simulation is doing its job, then your job is impossible**. Sorry, that's the blessing & curse of software for you. Here are some more imperfect ideas:

1. Use `GetKeyboardState` and verify that the button states are correct. If the message faker is using `PostMessage`, they will likely not be setting keyboard state and this would indicate fakery.
2. If you are targeting known applications that are doing the input simulation, detect them and complain. This is not perfect at all for many reasons.
3. Fuzzy logic, as many other people have suggested.

You need to be creative and figure out the difference between a simulated event and a real one **to you**, as there is no generalized answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done (reliably (with software alone anyway))

I've used WIN32API calls to read pixels/manipulate the mouse/send keystrokes to automate large portions of video games and other repetitive tasks.  You could write a lot of code to analyze the input, but equally smart developers are just going to modify their code to match.

When I first try to automate a mouse click, that's all I'll do.  Send a mouse click.  And most of the time it works.  You might have code that tracks the mouse movement and the entire stack of mouse events that would fire along with a legitimate click and say, 'That wasn't real - we ignore it' but nothing stops the developer from also implementing mouse movements.

The mouse events are more complex than keypresses; but it's essentially the same idea.  If you write code that monitors the time between keypresses and determine that I'm sending the '2' key to your application in EXACTLY 250ms intervals, you might decide I'm a bot.  But, all I'll do is modify my code to send the keystroke in 250ms + a random value between -25 and 25 ms.

It's a never-ending game of cat and mouse.  The best solution is to make tasks non-trivial so simple forms of automation aren't applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit thin on details.

Events can be sent directly to controls without moving the mouse so find out where the mouse is when you get the click event and see if it's on the control. Keyboard input requires control focus, so check that too.

For situations where the mouse moves, you won't be able to tell if the mouse movement is recorded and played back. If its scripted then perhaps you could monitor the mouse behavior in the parent panel(s) of the control and use those events and movements to ascertain whether it is real or not. An automated click might appear from nowhere and cause an flurry of unlikely hover, focus events.

Answer (score 1):

Only way it would be possible is with some specialist hardware and software on the mouse itself that sends evidence of the actual mechanical click.  Via software this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Although in my other answer I mention that you should ideally just respond to clicks as clicks, there is one possibility that could work, depending on how a "programmatic" click is generated.

I am assuming a Windows platform, due to the "vb.net" tag:

With the WinAPI you can send a message to any window in order to simulate, for example, a WM_LBUTTONDOWN event.  In this message you would include the X and Y location of the mouse at the time the button was pressed - or where the receiving program *expects* it to be.  When you handle the message you could use the [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call to get the actual cursor position. Verify that the current position is *close to* that in the message, and handle it as a click, otherwise ignore it.

Bear in mind however that the nature of the message queue is such that it could take some time to handle the event, and the mouse can move a long way in a short space of time.

This solution would only work if the "click" is generated by a simple Send/PostMessage. If the application that is generating the click simulates the movement of the mouse also, then you should probably see the other answers :)

Comment: That won't suffice unfortunately; it will cause way too many false positives. Message lag is going to mean that there is no threshold of "closeness" that will behave well. It's good food for thought though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to determine with perfect accuracy whether a mouse click is automated or not. I mean, you could write your own USB driver that sits in between the native mouse driver and the OS and relays only "real" clicks to you. However, even that can be defeated by plugging in a USB device (like a smartphone) that's programmed to send USB packets to host computer.

What are you trying to accomplish that requires you to distinguish between real mouse clicks and fake ones?

Answer (score 0):

Create a statistical learning solution by logging the past X mouse events in your program. When the user clicks on the control, determine the probability based on the last X actions that it's a real click.

Train your solution using real clicks and a large variety of automated scenarios.

This is obviously not a guaranteed-to-work solution and is more for fun than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more harder than what you think because input macro programs produce **legit** mouse and keyboard input messages to your game. I don't think there is a way to check if the input message is actually triggered by a physical hardware input (like  mouse or keyboard) unless OS provides you with accessibility of input-driver-level.

Since this is specifically for a game, you can see how other games handle this situation. Some of the common methods are,

1. Check **frequency** of mouse clicks. (human beings cannot click as fast as programs.)
2. At random points or when it doubts, use [**CAPTCHA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to verify. (Read this: http://www.threadmeters.com/v-1Vvd/CAPTCHA_The_Obvious_AntiBot_Solution/ )
3. Use outside **monitoring tools** to inspect all processes running in a machine to find out programs known for cheating purpose. Steam does this. Check [Valve Anti-Cheat System](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7849-Radz-6869) Blizzard's WoW also does the same thing with [Warden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warden_(software)).

My own advice would be "**Use your gameplay system**". Since every game has its own rules and gameplay styles, it wouldn't be too hard to detect whether a player is cheating or not. This approach won't be a general solution and it could be silly but if it works for your game, why not? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could work around this problem.

1. Make a new Button with a Text proving that the user isn't AFK and if the user doesn't press the button, kick him or her out. Generate the button in random locations.
2. If the user isn't moving for a while, (for example, 10 mins) kick him or her out.