# How can I detect artificial mouse movements?

Tags: windows, mouse

We wrote a game where you shoot targets as quickly as you can, and someone wrote a program to automatically shoot the targets (via simulated mouse movement/clicks).

How can I detect this? I thought of monitoring mouse speed, etc., but it seems too easy to get around. If it helps, the game runs on Windows / is written in C++. Is there no way to just tell that the movement isn't coming from hardware?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to rely on heuristics.

Comment: What framework are you using? Win32? DirectX? Something else?

Comment: Build the next hack-proof mouse that has an extra sensor for movement. Oh wait...

Comment: Do a Turing test either during game startup or during game, i.e the "grip" on a gun or whatever, change it so automated scripts will fail as they will not understand where to supply mouse input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to detect if mouse click is legit or automated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091780/how-to-detect-if-mouse-click-is-legit-or-automated) Essentially it says that it can't be done reliably, because of several reasons, one of which is that the programmer will find a way to get around whatever you try to do.

As suggested, heuristics seem to be a viable option. Monitor variable mouse speed, miss rates and accuracy, pauses, sudden jumps, et c. The better the heuristics get, the more the programmer will have to make his bot closer to a real player, and the less successful he gets.

PS: Even for well known shooter games like Counter Strike, there are [hacks](http://www.hackpconline.com/2010/02/top-5-counter-strike-hacks-cheats.html) that shoot everything perfectly for you , so they haven't figured out how / don't want to stop it either.