# Delphi - identify mouse click source (hardware vs virtual click)

Tags: delphi, touch, mouse

This time something what I had troubles to find title for...

I'm using windows hooks ( TMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT ~ WH_MOUSE ) to follow mouse movements and mouse button clicks...

This all works fine, however, I want to know whether is there a way to determine the mouse move/click source?

Either if it's possible to identify it by either device ID, or maybe source type (mouse, trackball, touchscreen...), or at least if it was sent from hardware source at all (aka, was it hardware or some mouse recorder macro, or other app's "SetCursor" procedure).

The main goal I'm looking for here is to find a way to block the ability to use mouse recorder to make clicks inside my app (so while in focus, I'd start a mouse hook and in case the move / click was made by software, I'd ignore any actions made..)

This could be asked as "How to block mouse recorder macros in my app" but I'd rather see an actual solution to identify the source as well (and as primary answer), as it might have other uses too.

Thanks.

Edit:
One way would be to check whether the mouse movement was made on snap or slowly (like actually moving the mouse). However, here then the problem persists with touchscreens.
Though, on the other hand - Windows does detect when touch was used (cursor is changed for the dot onscreen), so there surely is a way to at least separate mouse from touch events -> and knowing that would already solve a lot, combined to decline snap-actions on mouse only...

Comment: FYI: I know similar theme was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091780/how-to-detect-if-mouse-click-is-legit-or-automated  but the question is not the same  (touch screen info), so please do not report as duplicate, as it's not.

Comment: Did you take in account to use the Sender Parameter:

Procedure MenuOnClick(Sender:TObject);
begin
ReactOnClick(FromMenu);
end;

Comment: @ChristineRoss I don't really understand what you mean. The button is there, the user can click on it, and it will react. The same now happens if mouse recorder is used and user records the mouse position and click on that button. That is what I'm trying to eliminate using some kind of hardware vs software click detector. Am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: @ChristineRoss The sender parameter of OnClick, OnMousedown, OnMouseUp, OnMouseMove, etc. does not tell you which hardware has caused that click or cursor movement but which component has fired that event. This is useful for reusing of a single event method for multiple components.

Comment: @JustMarc I suggest that you don't proceed with implementing of this solution. Why? Are you aware that some Trackpads and Touchaprds are actually generating these messages programmatically. So your solution could actually lead into your users in being unable to use of your software because of that. Also this would mean that your program would be ignoring other valid inputs like inputs received during remote assistance session.

Comment: @JustMarc Also what about Windows Accessibility features? They are also moving the mouse and creating mouse clicks programmatically. In short I don't thing you have a god idea here for solving of your problem.

Comment: @SilverWarior: "This is useful for reusing of a single event method for multiple components" this is true when you use it as designed. But you can create a own special onevent procedure for every possible sender and you name the sender specific and you can identify who triggered the event. So don't use one procdure for all onclickevents, but use for all possible onclickevent a specific one. 

It is still true that you don't see if the sender is hardware or software.

Comment: Here an example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzAg0XZupfgTU2U1MElJSkJpdm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SilverWarior It's specific app. For specific end users. For a specific client that asked for it. It will only be used on 2 or 3 systems.  Accessibility or remote issue is not to be considered a problem at all, as well as any trackpads etc. Therefore I have to refuse your suggestion about proceeding here...

Comment: @ChristineRoss: "*But you can create a own special onevent procedure for every possible sender and you name the sender specific and you can identify who triggered the event*" - You can do that with a single event handler as well.  You can compare the `Sender` pointer itself to the individual component pointers. Or you can type-cast the `Sender` to `TComponent` and read its `Name` or `Tag` property. Or you can type-cast the `Sender` to whatever other common ancestor you need to access a different property that is shared by all of the senders.  Or use RTTI if there is no single common ancestor.

Comment: @ChristineRoss Does your code example even work? Because in the Button1Click you pas VAWIzBtn as parameter to your EDitVAActExecute method but in that method you check to see if that parameter points to some other component. Anyway basically in your code example you are doing similar thing that I described with the exception that you moved most of the code into separate method. BTW Why are you using `if statements` instead of `if...else if statements` or even better `case statements` when checking the Sender name?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, look at my example some comments above

Comment: @SilverWarior, Yes it works, I might have made some typing errors, because I shortened the code a little bit, but the principle works. I use only the information that the sender is TButton and has the name VAWizBtn.
I don't know if case would work. My feeling was that I don't need if ..else, because Sender is TButton or not

Comment: @ChristineRoss Oh my mistake. I overlooked that you have an if statement to check the sender type and then another nested if statement for checking the senders name. Which suggests that you should probably take some time in refactoring your code to increase its readability. And readability is the biggest problem of what I usually call mile long methods. Quickest way to improve readability without the need to rewrite the whole code is adding some nested regions which then gives you new code collapsing points.

Comment: @ChristineRoss You can check TCharacter.Attack and TCharacter.PhysicalDeffenseCalculation methods in my WIP RPG based combat system (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65300398/Programiranje/RpgBattleSystem.rar) to see the benefit of using Regions for increasing the code readability. Also feel free to take a look at the way how I'm using classes to achieve good data reusability.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I don't want to start a discussion about readability, but we have our internal rules how to format the code; they might be outdated or have other disadvantages,  but we are acquainted to them. Your example is for me not easier to read, you just follow other rules. You can follow the discussions here about the add on in Delphi Xe8 (forgot the name, sorry)

Comment: @ChristineRoss I wasn't trying to start discussion about code readability but I just wanted to point out some things. If they are useful to you fine. If not well they might come useful for someone else.

Comment: Interesting. Legit question, (unless I'm really dumb idiot who can't see what's wrong with it), receiving legit answer which seems to work, although some other topic (to which I did include the link) states it's not possible, and I still get a downvote on it?

Comment: +, it seems that somebody really loves me on here.   http://shrani.si/f/2H/Yf/2HzJC20L/printscreen2905201500952.png 
This is just from last 2 days. I think it's legit to say that came from single and same person...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Chen summed it up in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/15/10129271.aspx)

> There's no point discussing the possibility that the sender of the message is playing tricks and lying to you because (1) your program should just go along with the ruse and respond to fake [menu] messages as if they were real [menu] messages, because (2) **there's no way to tell that you're being lied to anyway.**

And [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/13/10499047.aspx) of his shows that all input ultimately goes through the same queue, so even Windows does not know the difference between real input and simulated input.

You should look into using the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) to receive [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) messages directly from hardware.  `SetCursor()`, `SendInput()`, macro players, etc cannot simulate those messages. And you would be able to differentiate between input from different devices, but not necessary the *type* of mouse if multiple mouse devices are being used. Although, since a trackball might have more capabilities than a standard mouse, it might represent itself as a HID device instead of a mouse device.

As for touchscreens, that type of input generates [`WM_TOUCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341.aspx) messages, which cannot be simulated, either.

So, between `WM_INPUT` and `WM_TOUCH`, you can differentiate between hardware mouse input and touchscreen input, at least.  Beyond that, simulated input is going to generate standard `WM_MOUSE...` and `WM_(L|M|R|X)BUTTON...` messages, which cannot differentiate between hardware input and simulated input, not even in lower-level mouse hooks.  You would probably need to keep track of the `WM_INPUT`/`WM_TOUCH` messages and match them up to the other messages, and if you cannot find a match then assume input is being simulated.

Comment: Actually you can read which mouse generated WM_INPUT message. This was used in several games to allow hot-seat multiplayer when each user would be using its own mouse.

Comment: @SilverWarior: if you read my answer more carefully, I did say that `WM_INPUT` can differentiate between different mouse devices.  That is one of its primary features, so that an app can use different devices to control different actions. You just would not be able to identify whether a given device is a standard moue vs a trackpad vs whatever, unless you have other means of gathering that information from other sources.

Comment: @JustMarc: `WM_INPUT` gives you the ID of the device that is generating the event. And you can use `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` to get some information about the device itself.

Comment: So, software caused clicks does not generate WM_INPUT  / ID, and can be eliminated this way, or would I still need to identify the mouse used, and then accept clicks from that ID only?

Comment: @JustMarc: No, software-generated clicks do not generate `WM_INPUT` messages. The RAW Input API is meant for receiving events from hardware directly. There is no hardware ID provided by software-generated clicks.

Comment: @JustMarc: What I described in my answer would be you detecting the `WM_INPUT` message first, looking at its data to see what type of action was performed (movement, click, etc) and then if you detect a subsequent `WM_MOUSE...` or `WM_(L|M|R|X)BUTTON...` message (or corresponding VCL `OnMouse...`/`OnClick` event) with similar information then it most likely was hardware-generated so process it, otherwise ignore it (or, just ignore it anyway and use `WM_INPUT` and `WM_TOUCH` for everything you need, at last while your app is in its special recorder-ignoring mode).

Comment: @RemyLebeau that sounds like exactly what I'm after. I dont get though, why the start with " there's no way to tell that you're being lied to anyway.".    Is it just if WM_INPUT is not used, or does WM_INPUT have some glitches as well?  Just out of curiosity... I learn so much everyday here, despite some harsh comments and things said.. it's very useful forum. And pretty much always same people answer to my ridiculous questions so... Thank you from the bottom of my young heart!! :)

Comment: If you just use a hook, it does not tell you if it is detecting simulated input or not.  If you just look at any given message's data by itself, it does not tell you if it is a simulated message or not.  So you have to corroborate multiple sources of information to figure out what is really going on.