# How to detect a Windows 8 Slate

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-8, tablet

I'm looking for a method to programatically detect Windows 8 Slate devices using C/C++. My definition of "Slate" is "a portable computing device equipped with a touchscreen but without a dedicated physical keyboard" (so including devices that come with a keyboard dock, but excluding laptops and tradition tablets where the physical keyboard is attached).

I tried using WMI Win32_SystemEnclosure and checking the ChassisTypes, but one Slate reported the ChassisTypes as being "Hand Held" and another reported "Main System Chassis", so this doesn't seem to be reliable.

Comment: I am not sure this will be possible. The hardware is changing rapidly, and there are already so many devices out there that fit in every category and then some. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a tendency  to eliminate the difference from the OS pov, as seen on Ubuntu, Win8, etc...

Comment: Maybe instead of detecting the device type, you should check if the device has a keyboard? It seems that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's definitely one of the conditions I'm looking for, @PawełStawarz. I'm not sure how to distinguish a physically-attached keyboard, though.

Comment: What if the keyboard can be covered of fold down like Lenovo Yoga or Vaio Duo?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc. Lenovo Yoga and Vaio Duo are "convertible" tablets, which don't fit my definition of a "slate" because they both have a permanently-attached physical keyboard.

Comment: but when the keyboard are covered they cannot be used either, and it's just like tablets

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: This scenario is covered by Microsoft using the `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CONVERTIBLESLATEMODE)` function. However, I'm only concerned with the scenario where there is no physical keyboard attached at all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to provide any code, since I don't have a "slate" device to test it on, but I can offer you some suggestions.

You'll probably want to use a heuristic sort of approach, using several API calls to determine the presence or status of various bits of hardware, then determine if the system matches what you're looking for. The [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) API is likely to be the most useful to you; after looking through some documentation, here are the calls that are likely to help you.

`GetSystemMetrics` with `SM_CONVERTIBLESLATEMODE`: returns 0 if the system is in Slate Mode and non-zero otherwise. There's no guarantee this will mean the system is an actual slate device, but it can at least tell you if the device has a slate *mode* and is using it.

`GetSystemMetrics` with `SM_DIGITIZER`: returns a bitfield value that tells you whether the system supports touch or a pen. If `GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER) & TABLET_CONFIG_NONE` evaluates to true, your device probably isn't a slate. You can also make good use of the other bitflags this call gives you access to.

`GetSystemMetrics` with `SM_MOUSEPRESENT`: tells you whether a mouse is present. This is a very weak test since the docs say virtual mice or sometimes just a mouse *port* will be enough to set this flag, but it's still worth testing. If a mouse isn't present, your device has a higher chance of being a slate.

`GetSystemMetrics` with `SM_TABLETPC`: similar to the `SM_DIGITIZER` test, this tells you if the Tablet PC Input service is started or not. If the service isn't started, your device probably isn't a tablet.

[`GetSystemPowerStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693(v=vs.85).aspx) could provide a few useful heuristics as well. This API returns a [`SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373232(v=vs.85).aspx) structure which you can test in the following ways:

- If `ACLineStatus` is 0, your device isn't connected to AC power, so it's more likely to be a slate.
- If `BatteryFlag` is 128, there is no system battery, so your device probably isn't a slate. If it's any other value (except 255, which is unknown status) there is a battery, which means your device is more likely to be a slate.

You can also look into [WMI's Win32_Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394166(v=vs.85).aspx), in particular its `Availability`, `ConfigManagerErrorCode`, and `Status` properties. At the end of the day [there is no way to determine whether keyboard input is from a physical or virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553777/detecting-simulated-keyboard-mouse-input/4554118#4554118), but you can at least attempt to test for a physical keyboard.

Your [WMI Win32_SystemEnclosure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394474(v=vs.85).aspx) test would become another heuristic in the list. See what `ChassisTypes` returns: `Desktop`, `Low Profile Desktop`, `Mini Tower`, `Tower`, and `Laptop` probably mean the device isn't a slate. `Pizza Box`, `Portable`, `Notebook` (although generally notebook == laptop in common verbiage, so this will require testing), `Hand Held`, `Space Saving`, and `Lunch Box` are probably more likely to be slates. You can also try to run calculations on the `Depth`, `Height`, `Width` and `Weight` properties, since anything over a certain size and weight probably won't be a portable device and therefore won't be a slate.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping not to resort to heuristics, but I may have to give in if no better way is found.

Answer (score 0):

Sample touch detection code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371581(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
// test for touch
int value = GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER);
if (value & NID_READY){ /* stack ready */}
if (value  & NID_MULTI_INPUT){
    /* digitizer is multitouch */ 
    MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Multitouch found", L"IsMulti!", MB_OK);
}
if (value & NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH){ /* Integrated touch */}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a specialist when it comes to WinAPI, but since noone else answered, maybe it will be of some help to you. On MSDN, there's a [list of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx#devices) awailable for Windows store apps, which also specifies whether functions can be used on handheld devices. Seems like the `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` contains exactly what you need - the `DeviceInformation` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.aspx).

All you have to do is list all the devices (there's code one the page which says how to do that), and search the list for a keyboard.

Please note: I don't own any Windows 8 device, so I can't really test if this is helpful or not. Give it a try, and I'll delete my comment if it won't help you out.

Comment: Thanks, @PawełStawarz. Unfortunately, I'm not building a Windows desktop application, so this API is not available for me.