# How to distinguish real keyboard or mouse input from command input like 'SendInput' by using hRawInput

Tags: windows, keyboard, hook, keyboard-events

After looking carefully at the spy++ in visual studio, I found out `hRawInput` when typing on the keyboard.

And I found that this value keeps changing every time I enter a key. 
Perhaps this value means the handle of what is called  `RawInput`, and i think the value of the hRawInput itself is meaningless.

But when approaching `RawInput` data through this handle, is there a way to distinguish between key input using SendInput and key input by a real keyboard?
If a method exists, what is the way to make the two indistinguishable?

In this question, [Detecting simulated keyboard/mouse input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553777/detecting-simulated-keyboard-mouse-input), someone says that the `SetWindowsHookEx` can distinguish between an input using `SendInput` and an input from a real keyboard.

However, `SetWindowsHookEx` is a function that is used to hook the movement of messages between OS message queue and application message queue, but `SendInput` is a function that operates on hardware queue that is a much lower level than that, so I don't understand how it is possible to distinguish.

To summarize the question is as follows.

1. By using `hRawInput`, How to distinguish input using SendInput between input from real device. And I want to know how to get `rawInput` data information through `hRawInput` of input obtained using SendInput or real device.
2. Even though `SetWindowsHookEx` works at OS queue-App queue and SendInput works at hardware queue, How to distinguish input using SendInput between input from real device.